# SQL query isn't working

Tags: mysql, sql

This SQL query isn't showing posts even though all of the "circumstances" are correct and are in the database.
Query - `$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE like BETWEEN 5 AND 25  AND bp='0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15 ";`

Why isn't this working? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`like` is a reserved word, so you need to escape it:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE `like` BETWEEN 5 AND 25  AND bp = '0'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 15 ;
```

Comment: maybe you could change your column name to likes? then you never have query problems anymore